# Test Conditionally Rendered component in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I'm new to testing and I'm writing test cases for a react app.

I've a table with atoms in it.

```
<Table.Cell style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
  <Icons
    data-test="nameDeleteTable"
    name="trash"
    onClick={() =>
     ConfirmBox({
      title: "Confirm Deleting?",
      message:
         "Are you sure you want to delete this entry permanently?",
      onClick: () => props.handleDelete(cell.name),
     })
    }
 />
</Table.Cell>
```

`ConfirmBox` has the following code

```
function ConfirmBox(props) {
  return (
    <div data-test="confirmboxAtom">
      {confirmAlert({
        title: `${props.title}`,
        message: `${props.message}`,
        buttons: [
          {
            label: "YES",
            onClick: props.onClick,
          },
          {
            label: "NO",
          },
        ],
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

`confirmAlert` is from a library named `react-confirm-alert`

The current attempt to test the table button click, gets to the onClick of `<Icons ... />` using the code

```
const wrapper = getWrapper(component, "nameDeleteTable");
console.log("Wrapper " , wrapper);
wrapper.props().onClick();
expect(wrapper.length).toBe(1);
```

While checking the coverage for this, I'm able to get the onClick function to be covered but not the onClick of the `ConfirmBox` and I have no clue how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to invoke a `onClick()` on whatever this `react-confirm-alert` renders to (I mean the html element).